# How to Publish WebMatrix site to Local File System?

Tags: publishing, webmatrix

Is there any option or workaround to first Publish Webmatrix Website to `File System` and then upload it manually, as we do in Web Projects and MVC Projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out, publishing WebMatrix Website is just copy-pasting whole website code to production server. But along with this you need to copy all assemblies from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\` to `Bin` directory of website.

Answer (score 0):

> ..Well I figured it out, publishing WebMatrix Website is just copy-pasting whole website...

Rather discerning,publishing will however do much more than copy paste, especially if transforms are involved...